# Which site to ask about basic phones?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to find out the specific file type of the default ringtones included on my basic phone, but can't figure out how to do so, if it's even possible with what I have.

What is the best site to ask this question?

I was thinking SuperUser or StackOverflow, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question.

I don't believe that there is a site on the Stack Exchange network for mobile phones at this time. Stack Overflow is definitely not the right site, because I don't think your question has to do with programming, and I don't think that Super User is a good fit either because it's not really about computers, either.

> Super User [...] is **not about** [...] electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
>
> *https://superuser.com/help/on-topic*

About basic phones in general, it's possible that Electrical Engineering would be a good site if the question had to do with electrical engineering, but this question doesn't appear to.

Unfortunately, there isn't a place on the Stack Exchange network for every question. [This Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) (closed) might have been a home for questions like these, but it apparently didn't make it. You might try restarting it if you really want to find the answer to your question with Stack Exchange, but it's probably easier to search elsewhere.